# Most compact way to write nondestructive shift

Tags: ruby

`arr.shift` will drop the first elm of an array, destructively mutating that array.  Sometimes you want the mutated array that results from applying shift, but don't want to mutate the original.  The following works:

```
arr[1..-1] || []
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is wrong with slicing like that seems very simple and non mutating but you could be more descriptive by using [slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice) or I guess you could call something like arr.last(arr.size - 1).

Comment: @engineersmnky: I usually prefer take and drop vs. accessing ranges too, because it's clearer at a glance. The thing about slicing in Ruby is that it requires both the start and the end and requires going through Ruby's slightly confusing range syntax (well, `..` vs `...` is subtle enough to fool my eyes sometimes, anyway). Saying "all but the first" with a single method is more easily digestible than the symbol-laden way of saying "from the second element up to and including the last."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for a less range-y way of saying "all but the first element of an array," I think what you want is `arr.drop 1`.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was looking for.  Ty Chuck.